# pm2 reload causes script launched by node to stop

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I am implementing zero downtime deployment on my nodejs express server.

I use this script to perform updates:

// deploy.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e
LOG_FILE="deploy.log"

echo ' Fetching changes from server' >> "$LOG_FILE"
git pull >> "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
echo '️ Building project' >> "$LOG_FILE"
npm run build >> "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
echo '♻️️ Reloading server' >> "$LOG_FILE"
pm2 reload server >> "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
```

This works great when I run it from the terminal. All works and all instances of my app are restarted.

However, I want to run this when I receive a webhook from Github that new code is available. I do this like this:

```js
app.post('/git-push', async (req, res) => {
    let start = new Date().toISOString();

    console.log(` Server deployment started ${start}`)

    const deployScript = spawn('bash', ['scripts/deploy.sh'], {
        cwd: process.cwd(),
        detached: true,
        stdio: 'ignore'
    });
    deployScript.unref()

    res.status(200).json({message: `ok ${start}`});
})
```

The bash script runs up to the point of `pm2 reload server` without a problem. During the reload though, i see that the request starts but doesn't finish.

deploy.log

```
// other logs from the other commands

♻️️ Reloading server
Use --update-env to update environment variables
[PM2] Applying action reloadProcessId on app [server](ids: [
   0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
   6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
  12, 13, 14, 15
])
```

if i do `pm2 list`, i also see that only a few instances are restarted, but not all. If i do `pm2 reload server` manually (after the webhook) from the terminal I get this error that reload hasn't finished and i should try again later.

---

How can I make sure that my bash script is not interrupted during pm2 reload?

Answer (score 0):

Worked around this by creating a dedicated separate server that handles the webhook and deploys the new changes.

updated `ecosystem.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            "name": "server",
            "script": "./dist/src/server.js",
            "instances": "3",
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "env": {"NODE_ENV": "production",},
            out_file: "./logs/out.log",
            error_file: "./logs/error.log",
            merge_logs: true,
            instance_var: 'APP_INSTANCE_SEQ',
        },
        {
            "name": "autodeploy",
            "script": "./dist/src/autodeploy.js",
            "instances": "1",
            out_file: "./logs/out.log",
            error_file: "./logs/error.log",
            merge_logs: true,
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: "production",
                PORT: 4000,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```